# Publishing status is not correctly reflected in queue

Tags: 2013, publishing, upgrade

After upgrading system from 2009 to 2013 SP1, when we publish items from Tridion, they are getting deployed successfully.
But the status of deployment is not reflected correctly in publishing queue.
We have already setup DCT both way, CMS and CDS.

Unable to see any error message in core log.

The publishing transaction haults in Different states in queue, even though it is successfully deployed on CDS.

Event Views lists following error :

> The partner transaction manager has disabled its support for
>   remote/network transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D025) The
>   partner transaction manager has disabled its support for
>   remote/network transactions. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8004D025)
>
> Component: Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing Errorcode: 0 User: NT
>   AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
>
> StackTrace Information Details:    at
>   System.Transactions.Oletx.ITransactionShim.Export(UInt32
>   whereaboutsSize, Byte[] whereabouts, Int32& cookieIndex, UInt32&
>   cookieSize, CoTaskMemHandle& cookieBuffer)    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetExportCookie(Transaction
>   transaction, Byte[] whereabouts)    at
>   System.Transactions.Oletx.OletxTransactionManager.ProxyException(COMException
>   comException)    at
>   System.Transactions.TransactionInterop.GetExportCookie(Transaction
>   transaction, Byte[] whereabouts)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.EnlistNonNull(Transaction
>   tx)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.PrepareConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionInternal obj, Transaction transaction)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry)    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.GetConnection()
>   at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.GetStoredProcedureCommand(StoredProcedureInvocation
>   storedProcedureInvocation)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.DatabaseUtilities.ExecuteNonQuery(StoredProcedureInvocation
>   storedProcedureInvocation)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.Sql.SqlDatabaseUtilities.ExecuteNonQuery(StoredProcedureInvocation
>   storedProcedureInvocation)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Data.AdoNet.SystemDataMapper.Tridion.ContentManager.Data.ISystemDataMapper.SetPublishState(TcmUri
>   publicationTargetUri, TcmUri processedItemUri, Boolean isPublished,
>   TcmUri userUri, TcmUri templateUri, Nullable`1 stateChangeDate)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishEngine.SetPublishToOnItems(IEnumerable`1
>   processedItems, Boolean isPublished, PublicationTarget
>   publicationTarget, User publisher, PublishTransaction
>   publishTransaction)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishEngine.SetPublishState(IEnumerable`1
>   processedItems, Boolean isPublished, PublicationTarget
>   publicationTarget, User publisher, Boolean isCalledFromFacade,
>   PublishTransaction publishTransaction)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.PublishEngine.SetPublishState(IEnumerable`1
>   processedItems, Boolean isPublished, PublicationTarget
>   publicationTarget, User publisher, PublishTransaction
>   publishTransaction)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Publisher.DeploymentFeedbackHandler.SetPublishStateOnProcessedItems(TransportFeedback
>   deploymentFeedback, PublishTransaction publishTransaction)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Publisher.DeploymentFeedbackHandler.UpdateStates(TransportFeedback
>   deploymentFeedback, PublishTransaction publishTransaction)    at
>   Tridion.ContentManager.Publishing.Publisher.DeploymentFeedbackHandler.DoWork()

Any suggestions, what could be missing here?

***EDIT:***

After configuring DTC properly, publishing status is not reflected in Queue.
Publishing is successfull with following error in cd_core log.

```
JAXBUtil - Unmarshalling failed.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.7.0_51]
    at com.tridion.util.JAXBUtil.unmarshalFromString(JAXBUtil.java:176) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.HTTPSTransportConnector.batchRetrieve(HTTPSTransportConnector.java:290) [cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.connection.connectors.TransportPoolConnector.batchRetrieve(TransportPoolConnector.java:85) [cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.DestinationController.poll(DestinationController.java:260) [cd_transport.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.transport.DestinationController.run(DestinationController.java:221) [cd_transport.jar:na]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.7.0_51]
```

Any suggestion would be a great help.

Comment: @Nuno We see the same lines at debug mode 
`DestinationController - Finished processing retrieved state files from destination: WeeQ3DtGWkyJdaUwJZ7oxw==`
Still we do not see status updated, instead in even viewer we see some error, as updated in question

Comment: Seems like your MSDTC is misconfigured. Ignore my previous answer, check if you have MSDTC properly configured between the CM and the SQL Server. You will probably see this error in other parts of the system, not only when publishing. More info here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7172223f-acbe-4472-8cdf-feec80fd2e64/the-partner-transaction-manager-has-disabled-its-support-for-remotenetwork-transactions?forum=adodotnetdataproviders (or google for the error)

Comment: You mean CMS server and CMS DB server(or broker DB server)?

Comment: CMS - CD does not use DTC, only CM

Comment: @NunoLinhares We enabled DTC on CMS Server and CMS DB Server. We are succesful DTCPing from both servers. After that if we publish anything, the following error occurs.
`JAXBUtil - Unmarshalling failed.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.`

Modified the question with full error log.

Comment: After removing (jaxb-api.jar & jaxb-impl.jar) from \bin\config directory at content delivery server, we are able to see the success message in queue now.
But when we publish to old (2009) CDS then content get published but status remains waiting for deployment and we get following error :
`INFO  MetaInfo - Could not read destination metadata, assuming unlimited window size
ERROR HTTPSTransportConnector - Batch could not be read, no notification data could be loaded`

Comment: You cannot publish to an older version of Tridion - the upgrade path, if you need to mix versions, is the other way around - CD first, CM later.